# How do I make the Firebase Admin SDK account respect validation rules?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a `node server` that runs the `firebase Admin SDK` and authenticates like so:

```
 admin.initializeApp({
        databaseURL: 'https://brandonsCoolApp.firebaseio.com',
        credential: admin.credential.cert(firebaseCredentials),
 })


 // firebase security rules (abridged version; i have several validation rules)
    {
      "rules": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null"
      }
    }
```

This works fine for normal operations. However, it gets a special status in the Firebase security/validation rules, and gets to ignore all rules.

I'd like it to respect validation rules.  So, in accordance with the [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start), I tried adding a custom `auth.uid` and adjusting my security rules:

```
 admin.initializeApp({
        databaseURL: 'https://brandonsCoolApp.firebaseio.com',
        credential: admin.credential.cert(firebaseCredentials),
        databaseAuthVariableOverride: {
          uid: "node-server"
        }
    })

// firebase security rules
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null || auth.uid == 'node-server'",
    ".write": "auth != null || auth.uid == 'node-server'"
  }
}

// I also tried this version
{
      "rules": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === 'node-server'",
        ".write": "auth.uid === 'node-server'"
      }
    }
```

However, this results in a `PERMISSION_DENIED` error when trying to call `update()` at any arbitrary path:

```
FIREBASE WARNING: update at / failed: permission_denied
{ [Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied] code: 'PERMISSION_DENIED' }
```

So: how can I convince my bad-boy `admin SDK server` to straighten-up and play by the rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I was on the right track with validation rules above. I was confusing the `PERMISSION DENIED` error for an authentication one, when in fact that's the same message you get when a validation rule fails.

Ultimately this `init` code worked:

```
admin.initializeApp({
        databaseURL: 'https://brandonsCoolApp.firebaseio.com',
        credential: admin.credential.cert(firebaseCredentials),
        databaseAuthVariableOverride: {
          uid: "node-server"
        }
    })

// firebase security rules
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null || auth.uid == 'node-server'",
    ".write": "auth != null || auth.uid == 'node-server'"
  }
}
```

I figured out what my validation error was by writing my `update()` payload to a `json` before calling `update()`, then copying/pasting the `json` content into the firebase Rules Simulator.  There, you get a line-by-line analysis of why an update failed.